# Why does the new Stack Exchange podcast take a long time to appear in ITunes?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, podcast

I see the Community Bulletin, get excited to listen to the new podcast, but am always disappointed when I can't download it on my Iphone. For example, Podcast #46 was posted on the blog last night. Today, at least 12 hours later, it is still not showing up on the [ITunes Stack Exchange podcast Url](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/the-stack-exchange-podcast/id279215411). This isn't the first time. What is causing the long delay?  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 'normal' Apple store delay problem; it normally takes 1 to 2 days for most podcasts to show up after publication, but it [can take longer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4064611?start=0&tstart=0).

This is not limited to Stack Exchange podcasts, and there is nothing either Stack Exchange or us can do about this.

In the meantime, podcast #46 has appeared on iTunes, so you can listen to it on your iDevice now:

[image: podcast #46]

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping we could blame Producer Alex for missing a step somewhere. :)

Comment: You can *always* blame Producer Alex. He probably won't care, and actually has all the power in podcast land, so it's kind of a waste of time, but it usually makes me feel better.